# Norm on graphs & functions with same nodes

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I was thinking of the following setting. Image we have a finite graph with nodes $V$, $|V| = n$. Furthermore we look at functions from each node into the real numbers, so $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
To each function we associate edges $E_f$, so the edges can change for different $f$. Edges could be defined by weights $w_{ij}^f$ and collected into a matrix $A_f \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
I was trying to define a norm and/or inner product on the space of $(f,A_f)$. Is there some obvious or sensible way to do this ?
I was thinking to define the squared distance between two elements $(f,A)$ and $(g,B)$ as
$||A-B||^2_F+||A \cdot f-B \cdot g||^2_E$, where $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm and $||\cdot||_2$ the Euclidean one. For example if we have two edge sets defined through $A$ resp $B$ with functions $f$ resp $g$ then if the Frobenius norm is zero we know they have the same edge set and if the euclidean one is zero we know the have the same image, For example take $A$ as some laplacian and $B$ as another one.

Forgive me for any ignorance on the subject. I am not even close to being knowledgable graph theory. Any literature and/or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what is "associating edges to function". Do you have some set of pairs (set of edges, function)? Or something else?

Comment: So basically I d have a function on the nodes, which are fixed. And for each function I have a matrix, the entries of the matrix can be interpreted as edge weights - if an entry a_ij is zero thered no edge at all. So the edges withits weigts change according to the functions. Does this make it clearer ??

Comment: In other words, you have a set of pairs (function on vertices, matrix), right?

Comment: Yes exactly, the vertices are always the same :)

Comment: This construction looks pretty strange to me if you require no correspondence between matrix and function. I think the most sane way is to take some norms on functions and matrices and just sum them. Also, your example doesn't give a norm - it's possible $A = B$ ,$f \neq g$ but $Af = Bg$.

Comment: Hi, yes it s true it s not a norm really. But it seems to me that it goes in the right direction. Assume for example that we have B=0 and g=0. Then we only consider A and f . Now if a node is not connected to others this reflecta in the matrix A and it will have no influence on Af, i.e at this node f could be whatever value we like. I d say this does make sense as when there is no edge there is no connection to the rest of the graph and so this node is unimportant.

Comment: Would you have other ideas besides taking the the sum ? I m not sure about taking the sum as the connection between A and f gets lost somehow